# Как создать прозрачный градиент маски с использованием фильтра SVG

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, svg

В настоящее время я использую градиент `SVG`, чтобы применить эффект `fade-out` для патчей.
Это позволяет начать путь с непрозрачностью `100%` в точке `x0` и постепенно уменьшать непрозрачность до `0%` в точке `x1`, где бы они не находились для конкретного пути,  к которому  применяется градиент:

```
<linearGradient id="gradient_to_transparent" x1="0%" x2="100%">
    <stop offset="0" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
    <stop offset="1" stop-opacity="0"></stop>
</linearGradient>
```

Это прекрасно работает при применении к стилю обводки контура:

```
<path d="..." style="stroke:url(#gradient_to_transparent);"></path>
```

Однако проблема заключается в том, что при использовании данного стиля обводки я не могу применить дополнительно другие стили обводки, и по умолчанию они остаются черными.

Я бы хотел, чтобы стиль обводки был выполнен с использованием любого цвета, который я назначу, а затем применить градиент к непрозрачности обводки или применить фильтр `SVG` для создания эффекта `fade-out`.

Я попытался использовать фильтры `SVG` - `feComponentTransfer` с `feFuncA`, но не смог получить то, что сработало бы.

Цвет обводки необходимо отдельно рассчитывать для каждого пути. Таким образом, решение установить цвет в градиенте не будет масштабироваться.

Перевод ответа: [How to create a transparency gradient mask using an SVG filter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21611795/7394871) @drarmstr

Comment: ассоциация : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21611795/how-to-create-a-transparency-gradient-mask-using-an-svg-filter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Должен ли он быть градиентом или фильтром? Я бы предложил использовать `<mask>`, который содержит прямоугольник с примененным градиентом, но я не уверен правильно ли я понял ваши требования.

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' width="1280" height="640"  viewBox="-20 20 400 80">

<defs>
 <linearGradient id="fadeGrad" y2="1" x2="0">
  <stop offset="0.5" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0"/>
  <stop offset="1" stop-color="white" stop-opacity=".5"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <mask id="fade" maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox">
  <rect width="1" height="1" fill="url(#fadeGrad)"/>
 </mask>
</defs>

<g id="web2.0-reflection">
 <text id="text" font-size="40" font-weight="bold" fill="yellowgreen" font-family="sans-serif" text-rendering="geometricPrecision">Instant Web 2.0
</text>
 <use xlink:href="#text" transform="scale(1 -1)" mask="url(#fade)"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Смотрите аналогичный [пример](http://dahlstr%C3%B6m.net/svg/presentations/svgdemos/relect-text-mask.svg)

Перевод ответа: [How to create a transparency gradient mask using an SVG filter @Erik Dahlström](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21929094/7394871)

Answer (score 3):

### Пример анимации SVG

Код взят из примера ниже.
Добавлены последовательные  анимации букв с помощью команд `skewX()` и `skewY()` 
реализующие вращение букв вокруг осей `X`и `Y` соответственно.

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' width="1280" height="640"  viewBox="-20 20 400 80">
 
 <defs>
  <linearGradient id="fadeGrad" y2="1" x2="0">
   <stop offset="0.5" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0"/>
   <stop offset="1" stop-color="white" stop-opacity=".5"/>
  </linearGradient>
  <mask id="fade" maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox">
   <rect width="1" height="1" fill="url(#fadeGrad)"/>
  </mask>
 </defs>
 
 <g id="web2.0-reflection">
  <text id="text" font-size="40" font-weight="bold" fill="purple" font-family="sans-serif" text-rendering="geometricPrecision">Instant Web 2.0
   <animateTransform id="an1" attributeName="transform" type="skewX" values="0;50;0;-50;0" begin="0;an2.end" dur="8s" repeatCount="1"/> 
   <animateTransform id="an2" attributeName="transform" type="skewY" values="0;3;0;-3;0" begin="an1.end" dur="5s" repeatCount="1"/>
  </text>
  <use xlink:href="#text" transform="scale(1 -1)" mask="url(#fade)"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```

Код взят из примера ниже.
Добавлены последовательные  анимации букв с помощью команд `skewX()` и `skewY()`